# BreezeJS and Windows Mobile Service Inserting/Updating a Record

Tags: javascript, breeze, azure-mobile-services

I had no issues hooking up breeze to querying the azure mobile services rest endpoints however I was not able to figure out how to perform an update/insert.

Doing something like this works great except for the save part.

```
var datas = new breeze.DataService({
    hasServerMetadata: false,
    serviceName: serviceName   // my endpoint
});

var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({ dataService: datas });
// manager.enableSaveQueuing(true);

var qu = breeze.EntityQuery.from("notification").where("id", "==", 1);

manager.executeQuery(qu).then(function (data) {
    data.results[0].isRead = false;
    console.log(manager.hasChanges());
    manager.saveChanges();
});
```

How can we use breezejs with the azure mobile service to either insert or update records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that you're not getting metadata from the service (you set `hasServerMetadata: false`) and you aren't defining any metadata on the client. Therefore you have an empty BreezeJS entity model which means that every query returns raw JavaScript objects **not Breeze entities**.

These raw objects are not in cache, they are not change tracked, they don't have any property change notification or binding support. They are just data.

`manager.hasChanges()` will always be false and `manager.saveChanges()` won't do anything ... because you never have any entities.

I haven't tried Breeze with AMS (aka "ZUMO") yet and don't know much about it. I'm sure that it will work with Breeze. But someone has to put in some time to discover how to get metadata from the server, how to insert/update/delete,  and how ZUMO data flow over the wire.

My understanding is that ZUMO objects are flat objects that map directly to SQL Azure tables. They have no associations with other entities/tables and that you have to manage foreign keys and related-entity loads by hand.  It's really not ready for the rich object models typical of business applications.

For the moment, I suggest you stick with ZUMO's own client component for accessing data.

We'll have a Breeze story in due time.